# Delete duplicates with different account name in SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates

```
Account                TicketNumber Status  Age
ABC, INC.              ABC500071    open    29
ABC, INC.(Power)       ABC500071    open    29
ABC, INC.              ABC500072    WIP     14
ABC, INC.(Energy)      ABC500072    WIP     14
ABC, INC.(Power)       ABC500073    WIP     14
ABC, INC.              ABC500073    WIP     14
ABC, INC.              ABC500084    WIP     14
ABC, INC.(Energy)      ABC500084    WIP     14
```

I want to delete duplicate ticket only with account name **ABC, INC.** leaving the other account name and ticket.

I tried several ways but was not getting the expected results.

Comment: Can you please specify DBMS and your sample query

Comment: Can you provide the query that you tried?

Comment: Can you specify the duplication, its difficult to see based on your dataset

Comment: You want to delete the extra `Account` for each `TicketNumber`? Will the order always follow a `Name` > `Name (Something)` type of pattern?

Comment: Yes, Shawn. the pattern is same

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Could you explain why the obvious `DELETE FROM table WHERE Account = 'ABC, INC.'` isn't correct?

Comment: @Edward Reverse the `LIKE` to a `NOT LIKE`, and I think that would satisfy the particular example given, but I'm not sure how performance would be on a larger dataset. The OP's example illustrates an incomplete requirement. We need more info to give a good response.

Comment: Not sure why I couldn't edit my comment anyways. @Shawn is correct. I was being flippant when I posted that. Joakim would be the better way.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 1):

You could try with an EXISTS clause.
But the syntax for that depends a bit on the targeted DBMS.

**PostgreSQL & Oracle :**

```
DELETE 
FROM yourtable t
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM yourtable d
  WHERE d.TicketNumber = t.TicketNumber
    AND d.Status = t.Status
    AND d.Age = t.Age
    AND d.Account LIKE CONCAT(t.Account,'%(%')
);
```

**MS SQL Server :**

```
DELETE t
FROM yourtable t
WHERE EXISTS
(
     SELECT 1
     FROM yourtable d
     WHERE d.TicketNumber = t.TicketNumber
       AND d.Status = t.Status
       AND d.Age = t.Age
       AND d.Account LIKE CONCAT(t.Account, '%(%')
);
```

**MySql & MariaDB**

MySql seems to have issues when using the same table in the EXISTS.
But with a little trick, using a sub-query, then it'll also work in MySql.

```
DELETE t
FROM yourtable t
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM (select * from yourtable where Account like '%(%') d
  WHERE d.TicketNumber = t.TicketNumber
    AND d.Status = t.Status
    AND d.Age = t.Age
    AND d.Account LIKE CONCAT(t.Account,'%(%')
);
```

**Sample Data used:**

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable (Account varchar(30), TicketNumber varchar(10), Status varchar(10), Age int);
INSERT INTO yourtable (Account, TicketNumber, Status, Age) values
 ('ABC, INC.', 'ABC500071','open', 29)
,('ABC, INC.(Power)', 'ABC500071', 'open', 29)
,('ABC, INC.', 'ABC500072', 'WIP', 14)
,('ABC, INC.(Energy)', 'ABC500072', 'WIP', 14)
,('ABC, INC.(Power)', 'ABC500073', 'WIP', 14)
,('ABC, INC.', 'ABC500073', 'WIP', 14)
,('ABC, INC.', 'ABC500084', 'WIP', 14)
,('ABC, INC.(Energy)', 'ABC500084', 'WIP', 14)
,('DEF, INC.(Energy)', 'ABC500085', 'WIP', 42)
,('DEF, INC.', 'ABC500085', 'WIP', 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you mean that you want to keep the rows that include `(Power)' or '(Energy)' and delete the others.

If your DBMS can use CTEs, you can accomplish this with:

```
; WITH q1 AS (
  SELECT * 
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY TicketNumber ORDER BY Account ) AS rn
  FROM t1 
)
DELETE
FROM q1 
WHERE rn = 1
;
```

EDIT: If your DBMS doesn't use CTEs (like MySQL 5.x or less), then you can use

```
DELETE t1
FROM t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT min(t2.Account) AS mainAccount
    , t2.TicketNumber
    , t2.Status
    , t2.Age
  FROM t1 t2
  GROUP BY t2.TicketNumber, t2.Status, t2.Age
) s1 ON t1.TicketNumber = s1.TicketNumber 
  AND t1.Status = s1.Status 
  AND t1.Age = s1.Age
  AND t1.Account = s1.mainAccount
;
```

Granted, this also relies on the fact that the `Account` can be reliably sorted in such a way that you can identify the row that needs to be deleted.

A WORD OF CAUTION: If you run the `DELETE` more than once, it will continue to delete rows until there are none left. Watch for this.

Comment: This one can get edge-casey very fast. So watch that you don't accidentally delete things you didn't intend to.